# Setting Up Intern for Javascript Project

Tags: javascript, intern

I know there are a couple of similar questions already answered ([Testing custom JavaScript (not Node module) with Intern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325697/testing-custom-javascript-not-node-module-with-intern) and [Can't get Intern to run Node.js Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466115/cant-get-intern-to-run-node-js-module)), but even after reading those answers, I've still been unable to get some simple tests to run using Intern. I feel like there is just one small piece that I am overlooking or missing.

I am trying to evaluate Intern for use with an existing Javascript project. It's not a Node project, just plain Javascript. If it matters, I am trying to perform this evaluation on a Windows machine.

1. My project hierarchy looks like this:

   ```
   APEFIntern/
       apeform/
           test/
               intern.js      - Intern configuration
               spec_inwf.js   - Tests for inwf
           inwf.js            - Code to test
       intern/
   ```
2. Intern configuration file:

   ```
   // ...

   // Configuration options for the module loader; any AMD configuration options supported by the Dojo loader can be
   // used here
   loader: {
       // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
       //packages: [ 'apeform' ]
   },

   // Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
   suites: [ 'apeform/test/spec_inwf' ],

   // ...
   ```

   I'm pretty new to Node and AMD, but I believe that since my project is not a node project, I do not need to use the loader.packages configuration?
3. Test file spec_inwf.js

   ```
   define([
   'intern!bdd',
   'intern!chai!expect',
   'apeform/inwf.js'
   ], function (bdd, expect) {
       with (bdd) {
           describe("inwf suite", function () {
               // Tests
           });
       }
   });
   ```
4. I execute the following command to try and run the tests:

   ```
   node client.js config=apeform/test/intern
   ```

   The only output I receive from the command is:

   ```
   Defaulting to "console" reporter
   ```

If I set the suites array to be empty in the Intern configuration, I get the message "0/0 tests passed" when I execute the command in #4. I believe this is the correct output. But whenever I try to connect to a test suite, the tests aren't run. I'm not sure what else I'm missing from this equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a small syntax issue in your `spec_inwf.js` test file:

```
'intern!chai!expect',
```

should be

```
'intern/chai!expect',
```

Everything else looks fine with your setup.

*Note*: your statement about not needing to use the `loader.packages` config if your project isn't a Node project is not really accurate. You don't need to use it in this particular case with the file structure you provided, however. [The amdjs packages documentation](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/Common-Config#packages-) may be worth a read for a better understanding of this configuration option, as it is AMD-specific, not Intern specific. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how many times I must have overlooked that issue. I will take a look at the link you provided. Intern is really starting to look like an incredible tool.

Comment: Is the above answer accurate for Intern 1.1? It appears that it is not in light of https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Changelog#since-10 where the intern dir is placed under node_modules dir not as a sibling of the project. Please describe a proper location of test files, config file, modules being tested and the web root.